# Конвертация координат EGSP:6335000 (МГГТ / МСК-77) в WGS84

Tags: python, координаты

Есть ли решения по конвертации координат МГГТ в WGS84? У меня тысячи объектов и руками такое не реально конвертировать. В pyproj, к сожалению, нет координат МГГТ.
Пример полигона:

```
[[[2678.41, 12170.9], [2677.266, 12169.947], [2670.956, 12164.564], [2667.604, 12161.802], [2659.053, 12154.372], [2659.61, 12153.681], [2658.1, 12152.509], [2657.614, 12153.068], [2649.996, 12147.291], [2648.612, 12146.152], [2643.213, 12141.522], [2632.174, 12132.054], [2629.108, 12129.424], [2624.693, 12125.769], [2617.412, 12119.743], [2608.339, 12112.417], [2607.152, 12111.458], [2606.122, 12110.627], [2605.967, 12110.494], [2606.379, 12110.294], [2606.335, 12110.139], [2600.568, 12105.58], [2596.369, 12101.965], [2589.446, 12096.079], [2575.025, 12083.566], [2570.313, 12079.969], [2569.272, 12079.045], [2567.775, 12077.614], [2566.867, 12076.843], [2565.364, 12075.566], [2556.848, 12068.331], [2555.04, 12066.817], [2550.912, 12063.261], [2549.958, 12062.438], [2548.785, 12061.468], [2547.828, 12060.677], [2547.378, 12060.305], [2540.919, 12054.916], [2533.125, 12048.981], [2532.914, 12048.794], [2531.389, 12047.45], [2529.141, 12045.495], [2526.254, 12042.984], [2526.125, 12042.593], [2526.006, 12041.708], [2526.024, 12041.078], [2526.269, 12039.844], [2526.614, 12039.05], [2526.894, 12038.631], [2527.607, 12037.855], [2527.665, 12037.809], [2525.557, 12038.487], [2524.769, 12038.741], [2525.329, 12036.689], [2525.697, 12035.77], [2526.061, 12035.016], [2526.635, 12034.002], [2527.171, 12033.247], [2527.574, 12032.749], [2528.302, 12032.013], [2529.158, 12031.269], [2529.475, 12031.025], [2530.34, 12030.544], [2531.368, 12029.97], [2529.406, 12030.736], [2522.636, 12033.398], [2516.556, 12035.788], [2506.495, 12039.674], [2498.569, 12042.707], [2494.977, 12044.081], [2483.459, 12048.489], [2484.538, 12054.069], [2487.194, 12052.903], [2491.296, 12052.048], [2494.43, 12052.211], [2496.904, 12053.182], [2498.67, 12054.394], [2502.157, 12056.77], [2509.21, 12061.687], [2518.708, 12068.405], [2519.285, 12068.813], [2528.288, 12075.198], [2529.713, 12076.209], [2531.574, 12076.799], [2532.61, 12077.245], [2536.094, 12079.631], [2540.295, 12082.648], [2540.652, 12082.922], [2540.83, 12083.036], [2541.007, 12083.125], [2541.096, 12083.156], [2541.272, 12083.189], [2541.36, 12083.187], [2541.491, 12083.16], [2541.553, 12083.136], [2541.676, 12083.066], [2541.79, 12082.974], [2541.923, 12082.824], [2541.978, 12082.74], [2542.043, 12082.608], [2542.065, 12082.541], [2542.086, 12082.44], [2542.089, 12082.341], [2542.083, 12082.276], [2542.052, 12082.148], [2541.967, 12081.96], [2541.892, 12081.836], [2547.454, 12085.948], [2547.016, 12085.885], [2546.803, 12085.876], [2546.599, 12085.894], [2546.501, 12085.916], [2546.396, 12085.952], [2546.195, 12086.056], [2546.003, 12086.194], [2545.88, 12086.299], [2545.638, 12086.526], [2558.804, 12096.092], [2564.305, 12101.383], [2565.666, 12102.636], [2570.959, 12107.168], [2572.287, 12108.393], [2586.382, 12120.512], [2600.706, 12132.461], [2604.263, 12135.557], [2608.341, 12139.104], [2610.4, 12140.896], [2618.394, 12147.851], [2619.629, 12149.106], [2621.081, 12150.938], [2622.836, 12153.369], [2623.429, 12155.885], [2625.191, 12157.402], [2625.441, 12157.617], [2629.357, 12160.987], [2633.927, 12164.721], [2634.948, 12165.556], [2636.063, 12166.467], [2638.088, 12168.122], [2638.406, 12168.04], [2639.128, 12167.876], [2639.851, 12167.712], [2639.992, 12167.57], [2640.133, 12167.428], [2640.63, 12167.92], [2641.1, 12168.386], [2642.209, 12169.484], [2642.563, 12169.834], [2643.472, 12170.735], [2644.165, 12171.421], [2645.052, 12172.299], [2646.326, 12173.535], [2649.198, 12176.319], [2650.272, 12177.361], [2652.07, 12179.103], [2654.941, 12181.888], [2655.113, 12182.054], [2655.288, 12182.224], [2655.69, 12182.648], [2656.132, 12183.115], [2662.573, 12189.372], [2662.677, 12189.473], [2675.236, 12202.296], [2684.151, 12211.469], [2696.201, 12223.062], [2709.891, 12237.899], [2720.754, 12249.832], [2722.098, 12251.308], [2734.933, 12265.419], [2746.039, 12277.963], [2758.882, 12292.703], [2766.859, 12301.866], [2773.047, 12308.969], [2774.809, 12310.991], [2779.515, 12317.486], [2783.875, 12324.358], [2789.156, 12329.798], [2789.623, 12330.682], [2793.107, 12337.278], [2794.098, 12336.884], [2798.235, 12343.642], [2801.194, 12348.498], [2806.939, 12359.915], [2808.144, 12362.377], [2808.386, 12362.871], [2809.594, 12365.654], [2809.825, 12366.099], [2811.552, 12370.419], [2811.737, 12370.884], [2813.02, 12373.756], [2813.213, 12374.218], [2815.621, 12379.984], [2816.23, 12381.444], [2818.973, 12388.011], [2819.603, 12389.985], [2820.226, 12391.962], [2820.841, 12393.942], [2821.448, 12395.923], [2822.048, 12397.907], [2822.64, 12399.894], [2823.224, 12401.882], [2823.361, 12402.353], [2823.801, 12403.873], [2824.37, 12405.866], [2824.931, 12407.862], [2825, 12408.11], [2825.485, 12409.859], [2825.638, 12410.419], [2826.031, 12411.859], [2826.498, 12413.595], [2826.569, 12413.86], [2827.1, 12415.864], [2827.458, 12417.627], [2826.438, 12417.863], [2828.593, 12428.033], [2830.797, 12438.723], [2830.601, 12438.763], [2830.799, 12438.736], [2830.894, 12439.43], [2831.138, 12441.222], [2832.828, 12455.84], [2832.836, 12455.911], [2833.528, 12464.734], [2833.696, 12468.588], [2833.963, 12475.085], [2834.016, 12477.285], [2834.11, 12481.098], [2834.154, 12483.028], [2834.199, 12485.027], [2834.17, 12486.225], [2834.151, 12487.037], [2834.054, 12491.035], [2833.958, 12495.034], [2833.955, 12495.178], [2833.788, 12499.034], [2833.746, 12500.009], [2833.616, 12503.031], [2833.586, 12503.73], [2833.516, 12505.354], [2833.37, 12506.7], [2832.94, 12510.677], [2832.509, 12514.654], [2832.423, 12515.445], [2832.253, 12516.354], [2831.829, 12518.609], [2831.479, 12520.474], [2831.091, 12522.541], [2830.548, 12525.428], [2830.34, 12526.472], [2829.833, 12529.007], [2829.536, 12530.393], [2828.698, 12534.304], [2828.637, 12534.591], [2828.537, 12534.992], [2828.264, 12536.084], [2828.158, 12536.508], [2828.279, 12536.543], [2827.826, 12538.142], [2821.45, 12560.638], [2821.081, 12561.587], [2816.53, 12573.27], [2817.289, 12573.54], [2816.527, 12573.276], [2814.571, 12578.013], [2807.012, 12593.294], [2802.409, 12602.391], [2800.814, 12605.422], [2798.001, 12610.558], [2795.787, 12614.18], [2794.038, 12616.886], [2791.901, 12619.737], [2786.078, 12628.045], [2779.983, 12636.163], [2771.522, 12646.964], [2766.971, 12651.914], [2766.919, 12651.97], [2763.708, 12655.409], [2763.662, 12655.459], [2756.737, 12662.937], [2756.546, 12662.849], [2753.993, 12665.606], [2753.93, 12665.674], [2750.2, 12669.513], [2750.144, 12669.572], [2747.86, 12671.951], [2738.965, 12681.216], [2736.676, 12683.628], [2728.36, 12692.386], [2726.706, 12694.128], [2723.898, 12697.29], [2720.46, 12701.161], [2714.057, 12708.241], [2711.622, 12710.933], [2710.825, 12711.814], [2709.223, 12713.599], [2707.602, 12715.366], [2705.96, 12717.116], [2704.299, 12718.849], [2702.619, 12720.563], [2700.92, 12722.259], [2699.293, 12723.849], [2699.202, 12723.937], [2697.466, 12725.596], [2695.713, 12727.235], [2693.941, 12728.855], [2692.152, 12730.455], [2690.346, 12732.035], [2688.524, 12733.595], [2686.685, 12735.134], [2685.576, 12736.072], [2684.92, 12736.627], [2683.132, 12738.095], [2681.323, 12739.539], [2679.494, 12740.958], [2677.644, 12742.351], [2677.446, 12742.496], [2675.774, 12743.718], [2673.885, 12745.059], [2671.977, 12746.373], [2670.829, 12747.14], [2670.05, 12747.66], [2669.358, 12748.109], [2668.107, 12748.919], [2666.146, 12750.15], [2666.112, 12750.171], [2664.169, 12751.353], [2662.176, 12752.528], [2660.168, 12753.674], [2658.463, 12754.66], [2656.746, 12755.628], [2655.018, 12756.578], [2653.28, 12757.508], [2651.531, 12758.42], [2649.772, 12759.313], [2648.003, 12760.186], [2647.405, 12760.474], [2646.225, 12761.04], [2644.438, 12761.875], [2642.679, 12762.672], [2642.642, 12762.689], [2640.837, 12763.484], [2639.025, 12764.259], [2637.204, 12765.014], [2635.376, 12765.748], [2634.693, 12766.013], [2634.446, 12766.108], [2633.429, 12766.503], [2631.477, 12767.248], [2629.52, 12767.981], [2627.56, 12768.704], [2625.595, 12769.415], [2623.627, 12770.115], [2621.654, 12770.805], [2619.678, 12771.483], [2617.698, 12772.15], [2615.714, 12772.806], [2613.727, 12773.451], [2611.736, 12774.084], [2609.742, 12774.706], [2607.744, 12775.317], [2607.706, 12775.329], [2601.522, 12776.556], [2601.44, 12776.577], [2601.472, 12776.362], [2601.422, 12776.169], [2600.744, 12776.344], [2598.666, 12776.882], [2596.868, 12777.321], [2595.984, 12777.537], [2593.293, 12778.155], [2592.977, 12778.223], [2590.592, 12778.736], [2589.065, 12779.042], [2587.882, 12779.279], [2585.164, 12779.785], [2585.141, 12779.789], [2582.44, 12780.252], [2581.198, 12780.448], [2579.709, 12780.682], [2577.245, 12781.035], [2576.973, 12781.074], [2574.232, 12781.428], [2573.282, 12781.537], [2571.487, 12781.744], [2569.308, 12781.964], [2568.739, 12782.021], [2565.989, 12782.26], [2565.328, 12782.308], [2563.288, 12782.457], [2563.236, 12782.461], [2561.34, 12782.572], [2561.106, 12782.586], [2561.118, 12782.785], [2554.8, 12783.156], [2548.14, 12783.672], [2539.065, 12784.376], [2538.338, 12784.411], [2535.98, 12784.503], [2533.622, 12784.574], [2531.263, 12784.623], [2530.671, 12784.629], [2530.225, 12784.635], [2528.904, 12784.65], [2526.546, 12784.655], [2524.976, 12784.644], [2524.188, 12784.638], [2521.807, 12784.601], [2521.812, 12784.801], [2521.112, 12784.816], [2520.354, 12784.833], [2518.882, 12784.851], [2517.409, 12784.856], [2517.107, 12784.854], [2515.936, 12784.846], [2514.462, 12784.822], [2513.103, 12784.787], [2512.989, 12784.784], [2511.517, 12784.731], [2510.044, 12784.665], [2509.102, 12784.613], [2508.573, 12784.584], [2507.103, 12784.489], [2505.633, 12784.38], [2505.106, 12784.336], [2504.166, 12784.257], [2502.699, 12784.119], [2501.213, 12783.966], [2501.119, 12783.955], [2499.978, 12783.832], [2497.142, 12783.523], [2494.266, 12783.211], [2493.665, 12783.163], [2493.168, 12783.123], [2490.281, 12782.891], [2489.345, 12782.816], [2489.181, 12782.802], [2485.194, 12782.482], [2481.207, 12782.162], [2481.088, 12782.152], [2480.748, 12782.125], [2477.378, 12780.874], [2473.627, 12779.482], [2469.877, 12778.091], [2466.127, 12776.699], [2464.339, 12776.036], [2463.97, 12777.113], [2448.908, 12771.947], [2445.387, 12770.815], [2426.581, 12764.767], [2414.892, 12761.129], [2407.777, 12758.915], [2406.538, 12758.53], [2405.344, 12758.066], [2404.156, 12757.5], [2402.996, 12756.845], [2401.884, 12756.114], [2400.845, 12755.32], [2399.902, 12754.468], [2399.119, 12753.442], [2398.494, 12752.265], [2398.002, 12751.024], [2397.935, 12750.815], [2397.821, 12750.461], [2397.603, 12749.788], [2397.226, 12748.523], [2396.883, 12747.235], [2396.597, 12745.936], [2396.391, 12744.642], [2396.288, 12743.367], [2396.286, 12742.556], [2396.326, 12742.114], [2396.483, 12741.391], [2395.153, 12743.245], [2394.232, 12744.527], [2384.605, 12757.944], [2375.52, 12770.605], [2375.989, 12774.154], [2386.88, 12773.49], [2394.622, 12776.092], [2400.555, 12778.086], [2401.28, 12778.33], [2409.774, 12781.185], [2410.853, 12781.465], [2425.953, 12786.762], [2457.422, 12797.601], [2478.605, 12803.253], [2478.823, 12803.311], [2490.686, 12805.442], [2493.043, 12805.733], [2495.404, 12805.998], [2497.768, 12806.237], [2500.136, 12806.449], [2504.325, 12806.862], [2507.254, 12806.927], [2509.63, 12807.033], [2511.489, 12807.095], [2512.007, 12807.113], [2514.385, 12807.165], [2516.763, 12807.191], [2519.14, 12807.191], [2521.516, 12807.164], [2523.892, 12807.11], [2526.265, 12807.03], [2527.221, 12806.906], [2530.19, 12806.375], [2535.297, 12805.862], [2554.863, 12804.101], [2556.941, 12804.024], [2560.938, 12803.877], [2564.935, 12803.729], [2568.933, 12803.582], [2572.93, 12803.435], [2574.711, 12803.369], [2576.309, 12803.28], [2576.92, 12803.242], [2577.909, 12803.18], [2579.509, 12803.067], [2580.907, 12802.958], [2581.107, 12802.943], [2582.705, 12802.807], [2584.302, 12802.659], [2584.886, 12802.601], [2585.898, 12802.5], [2587.492, 12802.328], [2588.86, 12802.171], [2589.086, 12802.145], [2590.677, 12801.951], [2592.268, 12801.744], [2592.824, 12801.668], [2593.856, 12801.526], [2595.442, 12801.296], [2596.779, 12801.093], [2597.027, 12801.055], [2600.663, 12800.206], [2604.558, 12799.296], [2608.453, 12798.387], [2612.348, 12797.477], [2616.244, 12796.568], [2620.139, 12795.658], [2622.53, 12795.1], [2627.326, 12793.343], [2628.022, 12793.121], [2628.039, 12793.115], [2628.95, 12792.824], [2630.571, 12792.292], [2632.187, 12791.746], [2633.799, 12791.188], [2635.406, 12790.616], [2637.009, 12790.031], [2638.607, 12789.433], [2640.2, 12788.822], [2641.788, 12788.198], [2643.371, 12787.562], [2644.948, 12786.912], [2646.52, 12786.25], [2648.087, 12785.575], [2649.647, 12784.887], [2658.774, 12780.636], [2665.094, 12777.522], [2679.349, 12769.034], [2693.004, 12759.57], [2705.062, 12749.844], [2705.607, 12749.405], [2706.544, 12748.649], [2708.57, 12746.744], [2711.484, 12744.004], [2713.974, 12741.663], [2714.368, 12741.249], [2717.124, 12738.351], [2719.881, 12735.452], [2722.638, 12732.554], [2725.394, 12729.656], [2728.151, 12726.757], [2730.908, 12723.859], [2733.664, 12720.961], [2736.421, 12718.062], [2736.484, 12717.996], [2739.082, 12715.084], [2741.745, 12712.099], [2744.408, 12709.114], [2746.49, 12706.78], [2747.052, 12706.12], [2747.189, 12705.957], [2747.903, 12705.146], [2748.629, 12704.345], [2749.369, 12703.555], [2749.756, 12703.156], [2749.859, 12703.049], [2752.652, 12700.385], [2753.538, 12699.539], [2755.697, 12697.771], [2756.861, 12696.817], [2757.427, 12696.354], [2759.001, 12695.482], [2760.237, 12694.797], [2760.253, 12694.789], [2763.722, 12690.134], [2763.747, 12690.092], [2766.79, 12685.109], [2779.974, 12669.847], [2785.604, 12663.377], [2789.856, 12658.491], [2798.799, 12645.889], [2798.437, 12645.442], [2797.966, 12644.861], [2798.546, 12644.194], [2800.111, 12642.374], [2800.198, 12642.272], [2810.799, 12629.938], [2815.933, 12621.227], [2816.716, 12619.899], [2826.698, 12601.037], [2832.359, 12588.736], [2832.481, 12588.471], [2837.708, 12577.115], [2840.658, 12573.038], [2843.78, 12566.213], [2853.15, 12545.73], [2851.812, 12543.906], [2850.933, 12542.362], [2850.055, 12540.819], [2849.23, 12539.21], [2848.94, 12538.012], [2848.82, 12537.518], [2848.298, 12535.476], [2848.06, 12534.122], [2848, 12533.31], [2851.08, 12533.25], [2853.686, 12537.112], [2854.4, 12538.17], [2857.7, 12536.4], [2861.168, 12534.964], [2860.938, 12534.406], [2860.518, 12533.248], [2860.152, 12532.072], [2859.84, 12530.883], [2859.713, 12530.29], [2859.583, 12529.684], [2859.38, 12528.472], [2859.278, 12527.562], [2859.197, 12526.641], [2859.138, 12525.717], [2859.104, 12524.864], [2860.151, 12514.676], [2861.633, 12498.085], [2862.193, 12482.112], [2862.252, 12481.399], [2862.504, 12475.913], [2862.502, 12474.385], [2862.471, 12473.776], [2862.491, 12472.856], [2862.472, 12471.296], [2862.447, 12469.8], [2862.412, 12468.272], [2862.386, 12467.326], [2862.372, 12466.815], [2862.37, 12466.744], [2862.32, 12465.217], [2862.261, 12463.689], [2862.195, 12462.162], [2862.121, 12460.636], [2862.038, 12459.11], [2861.948, 12457.584], [2861.85, 12456.059], [2861.744, 12454.534], [2861.629, 12453.01], [2861.507, 12451.486], [2861.377, 12449.964], [2861.239, 12448.441], [2861.093, 12446.92], [2860.939, 12445.399], [2860.772, 12443.836], [2860.769, 12443.811], [2860.408, 12441.29], [2860.142, 12439.481], [2859.867, 12437.674], [2859.827, 12437.421], [2859.584, 12435.868], [2858.88, 12432.047], [2858.085, 12427.84], [2857.655, 12425.225], [2857.038, 12421.47], [2856.685, 12419.676], [2856.323, 12417.885], [2855.954, 12416.094], [2855.577, 12414.306], [2855.192, 12412.519], [2854.953, 12411.499], [2854.452, 12409.387], [2854.092, 12407.896], [2853.943, 12407.277], [2853.426, 12405.169], [2852.902, 12403.063], [2852.369, 12400.959], [2850.834, 12395.374], [2850.163, 12392.562], [2849.592, 12390.468], [2849.014, 12388.376], [2848.428, 12386.286], [2847.834, 12384.198], [2847.232, 12382.113], [2846.623, 12380.03], [2846.341, 12379.079], [2846.005, 12377.949], [2842.843, 12370.119], [2841.922, 12367.839], [2841.195, 12366.039], [2837.858, 12358.617], [2836.019, 12354.525], [2833.422, 12349.981], [2830.064, 12344.104], [2827.136, 12337.052], [2826.871, 12336.414], [2825.643, 12334.244], [2822.931, 12329.389], [2822.415, 12328.464], [2820.413, 12324.879], [2818.387, 12321.7], [2817.643, 12320.532], [2816.401, 12318.583], [2815.205, 12316.706], [2811.239, 12311.038], [2810.751, 12310.34], [2808.851, 12306.537], [2803.672, 12300.741], [2798.543, 12294.571], [2795.075, 12290.531], [2786.626, 12280.687], [2783.619, 12276.823], [2769.409, 12262.247], [2762.758, 12255.475], [2760.968, 12253.612], [2757.437, 12250], [2756.398, 12248.938], [2753.095, 12245.201], [2750, 12241.931], [2745.215, 12237.101], [2739.218, 12230.771], [2732.043, 12222.957], [2720.098, 12210.569], [2717.099, 12207.125], [2715.187, 12205.043], [2712.237, 12202.02], [2706.07, 12195.96], [2703.304, 12193.079], [2699.875, 12189.503], [2688.628, 12179.302], [2683.152, 12174.834], [2682.193, 12174.052], [2678.41, 12170.9]], [[2847.95, 12529.82], [2848.168, 12528.281], [2850.548, 12511.502], [2851.886, 12497.392], [2852.296, 12490.096], [2852.442, 12487.453], [2852.507, 12486.056], [2852.518, 12485.794], [2852.564, 12484.659], [2852.614, 12483.261], [2852.655, 12481.864], [2852.688, 12480.466], [2852.713, 12479.068], [2852.731, 12477.67], [2852.74, 12476.272], [2852.74, 12475.864], [2852.741, 12474.873], [2852.734, 12473.475], [2852.72, 12472.077], [2852.697, 12470.679], [2852.666, 12469.281], [2852.544, 12467.181], [2852.095, 12459.466], [2852.451, 12450.093], [2852.612, 12446.59], [2852.972, 12438.742], [2856.982, 12437.867], [2857.21, 12439.52], [2857.404, 12440.991], [2857.591, 12442.463], [2857.769, 12443.935], [2857.782, 12444.045], [2857.957, 12445.11], [2858.125, 12446.176], [2858.284, 12447.243], [2858.435, 12448.312], [2858.579, 12449.381], [2858.715, 12450.452], [2858.842, 12451.523], [2858.962, 12452.596], [2859.074, 12453.669], [2859.129, 12454.239], [2859.274, 12455.818], [2859.361, 12456.894], [2859.441, 12457.97], [2859.513, 12459.047], [2859.577, 12460.124], [2859.633, 12461.202], [2859.681, 12462.28], [2859.721, 12463.358], [2859.753, 12464.437], [2859.777, 12465.516], [2859.793, 12466.595], [2859.796, 12466.911], [2859.801, 12467.674], [2859.801, 12468.753], [2859.793, 12469.832], [2859.777, 12470.911], [2859.77, 12471.232], [2859.753, 12471.99], [2859.721, 12473.069], [2859.681, 12474.147], [2859.633, 12475.225], [2859.608, 12475.729], [2859.266, 12482.747], [2858.815, 12492.003], [2858.664, 12495.102], [2858.469, 12499.119], [2858.426, 12500], [2858.281, 12502.98], [2855.425, 12525.87], [2855.04, 12528.61], [2854.759, 12529.133], [2854.058, 12529.774], [2853.42, 12530.29], [2847.95, 12529.82]], [[2751.065, 12247.578], [2750, 12248.679], [2748.95, 12249.765], [2748.794, 12249.926], [2748.668, 12250], [2747.638, 12250.6], [2747.013, 12250.848], [2746.092, 12251.003], [2745.547, 12250.926], [2744.443, 12250.429], [2743.967, 12250], [2743.815, 12249.863], [2741.131, 12246.781], [2746.51, 12245.34], [2738.029, 12236.512], [2735.52, 12233.9], [2735.153, 12233.524], [2732.372, 12230.682], [2731.482, 12231.567], [2729.998, 12229.8], [2730.763, 12229.038], [2726.5, 12224.68], [2720.94, 12226.05], [2710.008, 12214.47], [2710.195, 12214.184], [2709.41, 12213.399], [2709.09, 12213.687], [2704.935, 12209.291], [2709.98, 12207.13], [2701.61, 12198.69], [2699.793, 12196.858], [2690.128, 12187.48], [2680.719, 12177.722], [2681.138, 12177.303], [2697.218, 12191.114], [2701.343, 12195.19], [2703.98, 12197.99], [2717.397, 12212.236], [2729.573, 12224.838], [2736.576, 12232.115], [2737.35, 12232.92], [2739.461, 12235.112], [2743.318, 12239.117], [2750, 12246.451], [2751.065, 12247.578]], [[2851.287, 12408.573], [2847.516, 12409.006], [2839.712, 12391.318], [2836.118, 12380.922], [2836.142, 12380.895], [2829.391, 12363.072], [2834.675, 12360.048], [2837.639, 12366.39], [2838.251, 12367.953], [2839.914, 12372.197], [2842.426, 12378.609], [2842.566, 12378.964], [2842.726, 12379.419], [2842.885, 12379.874], [2843.044, 12380.329], [2843.202, 12380.785], [2843.359, 12381.241], [2843.516, 12381.698], [2843.672, 12382.154], [2843.827, 12382.611], [2843.981, 12383.068], [2844.134, 12383.526], [2844.287, 12383.983], [2844.439, 12384.441], [2844.59, 12384.899], [2844.741, 12385.357], [2844.89, 12385.816], [2845.039, 12386.275], [2845.187, 12386.734], [2845.335, 12387.193], [2845.481, 12387.653], [2845.627, 12388.113], [2845.772, 12388.573], [2845.917, 12389.033], [2846.06, 12389.494], [2846.203, 12389.955], [2846.345, 12390.416], [2846.486, 12390.877], [2846.627, 12391.338], [2846.767, 12391.8], [2846.906, 12392.262], [2847.044, 12392.724], [2847.181, 12393.187], [2847.318, 12393.649], [2847.454, 12394.112], [2847.589, 12394.575], [2847.723, 12395.039], [2847.857, 12395.502], [2847.99, 12395.966], [2848.122, 12396.43], [2848.253, 12396.894], [2848.384, 12397.359], [2848.513, 12397.823], [2848.642, 12398.288], [2848.707, 12398.523], [2848.771, 12398.753], [2848.898, 12399.219], [2849.025, 12399.684], [2849.151, 12400.15], [2849.276, 12400.616], [2849.4, 12401.082], [2849.524, 12401.548], [2849.647, 12402.015], [2849.769, 12402.481], [2849.89, 12402.948], [2850.01, 12403.415], [2850.13, 12403.883], [2850.249, 12404.35], [2850.367, 12404.818], [2850.485, 12405.286], [2850.601, 12405.754], [2850.717, 12406.222], [2850.832, 12406.691], [2850.946, 12407.16], [2851.06, 12407.628], [2851.287, 12408.573]], [[2817.983, 12340.861], [2816.902, 12339.065], [2822.625, 12338.927], [2821.97, 12337.77], [2821.903, 12337.654], [2821.309, 12336.616], [2820.644, 12335.465], [2819.975, 12334.317], [2819.3, 12333.171], [2818.62, 12332.028], [2817.936, 12330.888], [2817.247, 12329.751], [2816.554, 12328.617], [2815.855, 12327.485], [2813.745, 12323.818], [2810.753, 12324.521], [2808.753, 12324.99], [2808.322, 12324.203], [2811.837, 12323.38], [2813.295, 12323.039], [2812.812, 12322.356], [2810.414, 12318.969], [2809.087, 12316.975], [2807.744, 12314.992], [2806.384, 12313.02], [2803.194, 12308.188], [2793.412, 12295.81], [2787.702, 12296.594], [2783.76, 12291.843], [2783.434, 12291.506], [2783.127, 12291.128], [2782.845, 12290.709], [2782.596, 12290.252], [2782.386, 12289.76], [2782.221, 12289.238], [2782.107, 12288.693], [2782.049, 12288.131], [2782.049, 12287.562], [2782.108, 12286.994], [2782.224, 12286.437], [2782.396, 12285.899], [2782.619, 12285.388], [2783.324, 12284.374], [2784.658, 12283.153], [2789.632, 12289.141], [2788.846, 12289.848], [2789.818, 12290.915], [2790.666, 12290.299], [2793.046, 12292.852], [2797.355, 12297.835], [2799.972, 12301.168], [2805.103, 12307.704], [2813.977, 12321.131], [2820.728, 12331.347], [2824.189, 12337.749], [2824.533, 12338.387], [2826.977, 12342.908], [2827.911, 12344.636], [2826.179, 12345.063], [2824.04, 12345.066], [2822.019, 12344.657], [2821.103, 12344.104], [2819.789, 12342.922], [2819.553, 12342.653], [2817.983, 12340.861]], [[2773.315, 12280.196], [2772.15, 12279.26], [2777.46, 12277.538], [2767.799, 12267.616], [2759.393, 12258.969], [2754.033, 12260.535], [2753.483, 12259.787], [2753.171, 12259.363], [2752.89, 12258.901], [2752.646, 12258.403], [2752.445, 12257.874], [2752.291, 12257.32], [2752.191, 12256.748], [2752.145, 12256.164], [2752.156, 12255.578], [2752.223, 12254.996], [2752.345, 12254.428], [2752.518, 12253.88], [2752.739, 12253.359], [2753.001, 12252.871], [2753.299, 12252.419], [2753.626, 12252.006], [2753.977, 12251.635], [2754.344, 12251.306], [2758.754, 12255.753], [2767.446, 12264.52], [2781.347, 12278.809], [2781.095, 12279.187], [2780.802, 12279.554], [2780.467, 12279.905], [2780.09, 12280.235], [2779.673, 12280.535], [2779.22, 12280.799], [2778.735, 12281.022], [2778.223, 12281.198], [2777.692, 12281.322], [2777.15, 12281.392], [2776.606, 12281.407], [2776.066, 12281.368], [2775.54, 12281.277], [2775.034, 12281.137], [2774.554, 12280.953], [2774.106, 12280.731], [2773.692, 12280.477], [2773.315, 12280.196]], [[2655.348, 12155.603], [2667.794, 12166.076], [2667.503, 12166.319], [2668.264, 12167.125], [2668.583, 12166.763], [2676.171, 12173.161], [2671.943, 12174.741], [2663.542, 12166.485], [2656.25, 12159.404], [2653.285, 12156.405], [2655.348, 12155.603]], [[2832.929, 12356.439], [2827.956, 12359.284], [2827.627, 12358.416], [2827.293, 12357.207], [2827.377, 12356.502], [2827.548, 12355.816], [2827.801, 12355.164], [2828.127, 12354.561], [2828.512, 12354.017], [2830.448, 12352.102], [2832.929, 12356.439]]]
```

Comment: Вот здесь много интересного вроде на тему. Можно как-то извернуться, наверное, но нужно разбираться https://gis-lab.info/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19399 Где-то вроде можно `json` передать, где-то скопипастить. А где-то может и сайт через `requests` опросить, но нужно понять какие есть возможности, это нужно время и силы, чтобы с этим разбираться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдруг кому-то пригодится. Нашел также на стаке формулу для proj4

```
+proj=tmerc +ellps=bessel +towgs84=316.151,78.924,589.65,-1.57273,2.69209,2.34693,8.4507 +units=m +lon_0=37.5 +lat_0=55.66666666667 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
```

Пример кода для конвертации:

```py
import pyproj

proj_6335000 = pyproj.Proj('+proj=tmerc +ellps=bessel +towgs84=316.151,78.924,589.65,-1.57273,2.69209,2.34693,8.4507 +units=m +lon_0=37.5 +lat_0=55.66666666667 +k_0=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0') 
pyproj.transformer.transform(proj_6335000, 'WGS84', polygon_point[0], polygon_point[1])
```